# Slice a string in np.where

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
data = [10,20,30,40,50,60]    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Numbers'])
df['add_7'] = (df['Numbers'] + 7)
```

Here, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Numbers | add_7 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 17 |
| 20 | 27 |
| 30 | 37 |
| 40 | 47 |
| 50 | 57 |
| 60 | 67 |

What I want to accomplish, is that if the `add_7` column is a multiple of 3, then I want the first digit of `Number` as a string, otherwise "not a multiple of three", as a new column named "first_digit".

| Numbers | add_7 | first_digit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 17 | not a multiple of three |
| 20 | 27 | 2 |
| 30 | 37 | not a multiple of three |
| 40 | 47 | not a multiple of three |
| 50 | 57 | 5 |
| 60 | 67 | not a multiple of three |

I tried the following, but it seems that inside np.where, `df['Numbers']` is still a series instead of a single field, thus `df['Numbers'][0]` will always return 10.

```
 df['first_digit'] = np.where(df['add_7'] % 3 == 0, str(df['Numbers'][0]), 'not a multiple of three')
```

| Numbers | add_7 | first_digit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 17 | not a multiple of three |
| 20 | 27 | 10 |
| 30 | 37 | not a multiple of three |
| 40 | 47 | not a multiple of three |
| 50 | 57 | 10 |
| 60 | 67 | not a multiple of three |

What is the right way to specify that I only want to operate on the field of this row, not the entire column, in np.where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're close:

> str(df['Numbers'][0])

This looks at the 0th value of the column, and then stringifies that scalar, i.e, you get "10".

You need to stringify the column, and then get the 0th element of each value:

```py
df["Numbers"].astype(str).str[0]
```

Note that we use `.str[0]` to access 0th element of *each* value in the column; `[0]` would still access a single value, i.e., "10".